# How to align the ticklabel which contain upper and lower indices in MatPlotLib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a simple question about the position of ticklabels in matplotlib. I have written the follow code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

label = [r'$\mathregular{PM_{2.5}}$','OC',r'$\mathregular{SO_4^{2-}}$',\
r'$\mathregular{NH_4^{+}}$', r'$\mathregular{NO_3^{-}}$', \
"EC",r'$\mathregular{Cl^{-}}$','K','Al','Ca','Fe','Na','Mg','Zn','Pb','Ti','Ba','Mn','Cu']

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,2))
ax  = plt.subplot(111)
pos = np.arange(0,len(label),1)

ax.set_xlim(0-0.5,pos[-1]+0.5)
ax.set_xticks(pos)
ax.set_xticklabels(label, fontsize = 12)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Which produces:

[image]

However，the labels that contain both upper and lower indices are not aligned with other labels.

How to fix this issue to make sure that all the labels are placed along a horizontal line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use vertical alignment to the "baseline", together with an updated padding:

```
ax.set_xticklabels(label, fontsize = 12, va="baseline")
ax.tick_params(axis='x', pad=12)
```